# firebug does not show css details along with html/dom

Tags: firebug

Firebug does not show css details along with html/dom panel.
I get a single window/tab instead of two.

How can I configure/fix this to have the two (html & css) displayed together?

Comment: paste a snapshot of what you are having.

Comment: http://site2goal.bahr.co.il/FrebugHTMLbutNoCss.jpg

Comment: Got it to work!
Removed Java plugin and few add-on extensions.

Comment: I hope this will not be the standard to remove extensions and java plug-in. I think it's a bug.